Closed solution to a recurrence.
$q_{a+1}=q_a+2\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}q_k+1$
with $q_1 = 1$.
I'm looking at a random walk with three possibilities: up, down, middle; and trying to compute the amount of paths leading to the node next to the middle node at any level $a$.
The first 10 values of $q_a$ are: 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408, 985, 2378
I found this approximation for big values of a:
$q_a \approx (1+\sqrt{2})^{a-1}$
This gives: 1.0, 2.41, 5.83, 14.07, 33.97, 82.01, 197.99, 478.0, 1154.0, 2786.0
I found this approximation by looking at how the log of $q_a$ behaves and finding that (without proof):
$\log_{1+\sqrt{2}}{q_a}-\log_{1+\sqrt{2}}{q_{a-1}} \rightarrow 1$
How would I go about finding a closed form for $q_a$?

See OEIS sequence A000129.

@RobertIsrael Thank you very much!

Note that you can write that recurrence relation as $q_{a+1}=2q_a+q_{a-1}$ with one extra initial condition $q_2=2$. This is a second order homogeneous linear recurrence relation.

Let $Q(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1} q_n z^n$ be the ordinary generating function.  Then multiplying the recurrence by $z^{n+1}$ yields
\begin{align}
Q(z) - q_1 z &= \sum_{n\ge1} q_{n+1} z^{n+1} \\
&= \sum_{n\ge1} \left(q_n + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} q_k + 1\right) z^{n+1} \\
&= z \sum_{n\ge1} q_n z^n + 2\sum_{k\ge1} q_k \sum_{n\ge k+1} z^{n+1} + \sum_{n\ge1} z^{n+1} \\
&= z Q(z) + 2\sum_{k\ge1} q_k \frac{z^{k+2}}{1-z} + \frac{z^2}{1-z} \\
&= z Q(z) + \frac{2z^2}{1-z}Q(z) + \frac{z^2}{1-z} \\
\end{align}
Solving for $Q(z)$ yields
\begin{align}
Q(z) &= \frac{-z}{z^2+2z-1} \\
&= \frac{(\sqrt2-2)/4}{z+1-\sqrt2} - \frac{(\sqrt2+2)/4}{z+1+\sqrt2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\left(\frac{1}{1-(1+\sqrt2)z} - \frac{1}{1-(1-\sqrt2)z}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\left(\sum_{n\ge0}((1+\sqrt2)z)^n - \sum_{n\ge0}((1-\sqrt2)z)^n\right),
\end{align}
which implies that
$$q_n = \frac{(1+\sqrt2)^n-(1-\sqrt2)^n}{2\sqrt2}.$$

Thank you RobPratt!
